# SMBIOS Enum Values. Documentation error?

Tags: c++, windows, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write a simple parser for SMBIOS on Windows.

While reading the documentation for the 2.6.1 version (2.6 is the SMBIOS version on my laptop), I came across the System Information Entry (Type 1 - Section 3.3.2).

In the docs it says to be a BYTE value that represents the Wake-up Type is an Enum (i.e. a bit field in which each bit represents if a Wake-up Type is present or not, 1 or 0).

Now, in the following subsection 3.3.2.2, the Enum is defined for the bit offsets 00h through 08h making it a total of 9 bit values. A BYTE holds only 8 bits. Is the documentation wrong or am I missing something?

I just want to take the BYTE out of the structure and do an bit-wise AND to find out the Wake-up Type with the following masks :

```
#define SM_SI_OTHER             0x00000001
#define SM_SI_UNKNOWN           0x00000010
#define SM_SI_APM_TIMER         0x00000100
#define SM_SI_MODERN_RING       0x00001000
#define SM_SI_LAN_REMOTE        0x00010000
#define SM_SI_POWER_SWITCH      0x00100000
#define SM_SI_PCI_PME           0x01000000
#define SM_SI_AC_POWER_RESTORED 0x10000000
```

Here I'm missing the reserved value. How should I do this?

Here is a link to the documentation I used : http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.6.1.pdf

Thank you, in advance, for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the document and it says the field is an enum, not a bit mask.

Comment: I think you must have confused enums with bit masks.  While enums can be done in the style of bit masks, they generally are not.  In this case, the wake up type only holds one value at a time.  1 = other, 2 = unknown, 3 = timer, etc.